# A Python class inherited from a temporary class

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I got stuck when I try to figure out the following `codes`:

```
def with_metaclass(meta, base=object):
    print("[2]")
    return meta("NewBase", (base,), {})

class BaseForm(object):
    def __init__(self, fields, prefix=''):
       print(self.__class__)

    def say(self):
        print("BaseForm")


class FormMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print("[3]: {!r}, {!r}, {!r}, {!r}, {!r}".format(cls, name, type(cls), bases, attrs))
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("[4]: {!r}, {!r}".format(cls, type(cls)))
        return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

print("[1]")
class Form(with_metaclass(FormMeta, BaseForm)):
    print("[5]")
    def __init__(self):
        NewBase.__init__(self)
        print("[6]: {!r}, {!r}".format(self, type(self)))


# confused position
print(Form.__bases__)

# Form is based on NewBase, however, there is no NewBase
print(dir())
```

here is the code output:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]: <class '__main__.NewBase'>, 'NewBase', <class '__main__.FormMeta'>, (<class '__main__.BaseForm'>,), {}
[5]
[3]: <class '__main__.Form'>, 'Form', <class '__main__.FormMeta'>, (<class '__main__.NewBase'>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Form', '__init__': <function Form.__init__ at 0x7f6ad4d76f28>}
(<class '__main__.NewBase'>,)
['BaseForm', 'Form', 'FormMeta', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'with_metaclass']
```

Just like what I commented out, `Form` is base on `NewBase`, however, there is not a `NewBase` class in the main module. A class its base class is not accessible, is an error? But interesting, `Form` can still call the method, which comes from the parent of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the answer, we don't need the FormMeta class at first.
Imagine the definition of Form as follows:

```
class Form(with_metaclass(meta=type, base=BaseForm)):
    # ...
```

the `with_metaclass` call just returns `meta("NewBase", (base,), {})`, which in this case is just `type("NewBase", (base,), {})`, which creates a new class called `NewBase`, which is derived from `base` (`BaseForm` in this case), with no additional methods.
You can read about it at the [type documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

The `FormMeta` metaclass in this case does  nothing. It inherits `type` (that's why it is a meta class), and then just passes the data it receives on to `type`, plus some print statements. So it is essentially the same as above.
You can read more about metaclasses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear,  my question is that `Form` class based on `NewBase` class, but `NewBase` class is not in the module namespace, i.e `dir()`. So, the parent of `Form` class cannot be accessed. But the instance of  `Form` can access the method of `BaseForm` (the parent class of `NewBase`).

Comment: If you want it in the global name space, just use `NewForm = with_metaclass(FormMeta)`, and then `class Form(NewForm)`. Or just use `super():__init__` instead of `NewForm.__init__`. If that is not what you mean, I don't understand your problem